# std::valarray, std:vector or arma::vec?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, armadillo, valarray

I am not sure if this is the place for this question, but here it goes.

I am working on computational physics model in C++ and I received a big code that I am tiding up.

The field is quantum electronics, so there are lots of integrals and expressions, but my question concerns the optimization.

Initially the code needed 4 hours to finish the simulation, I tidied this up to 30 min after removing several bottlenecks.

What I still do not like is the fact that the data in the code (mostly arrays of type `double`) mix `std::vector<(double)>`, `std::valarray<(double)>` and armadilo's `arma::vec`.

Which one of these is the best way and should I even try to make uniform data type for the arrays?

I think the reason previous PhD students used `valarray` is its friendliness since operators `*`,`/`,`+`,`-` are overloaded and there is some scarce online promise that `valarray`s are faster then vectors (big online debate about this). 
Armadillo was brought in, due to its similarity to MATLAB syntax and extremely well documented library, and `std::vector<(T)>` is kept when T is class and not double.

I personally prefer armadillo, because it has very simple logic and it feels natural, `valarray`s annoy me sometimes because they do not have many member functions, but iteration through them is quite easy, vectors are very annoying, arithmetic operators are not overloaded for `<(double)>` and if I chose these I would probably need to make my own class for Array of `double`s which I do not really want to do.

Keep in mind that I have no idea how these arrays behave in memory, I started C++ last year, and I have a long way to go. I am planning of developing this code for 2 more dimensions (currently it's 1D) and execution time will certainly grow.

I am therefor seeking advice with which array type I should continue and should I make the code uniform (force all arrays of `double` to be of the same type (`std::valarray`, `std::vector` or `arma::vec`))

Comment: "which one is best" depends on a lot of things. If the purpose of these containers is to act as matrices or vectors (in the mathematical sense) then armadillo or eigen would make sense semantically and from a performance point of view. Honestly once these type of questions get too domain specific, I'd hop over to [Computational Science](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: For computation purpose Eigen is always the best choice. http://eigen.tuxfamily.org

Comment: [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net) is a good bet, with its clear syntax.  Eigen has a horrible API, where you spend more time debugging code than getting work done. A colleague doing computational physics simulations mentioned that using it is like "shaving a yak"

Comment: `std::vector<(T)>`: the parentheses look weird.

Comment: _"`std::vector<(T)>` is kept due to its polymorphism"_ and, setting aside the spurious parentheses, what polymorphism is that, exactly? I can't think of any. Besides, beyond the usual 'use `vector` unless you have a specific reason not to', I think this will be too broad and/or opinion-based to be useful for SO. CS as mentioned, or if you can get enough code to cite Code Review, are probably better places.

Comment: Sorry, I mixed std::vector with boost (which was also used in one place). I fixed what I wanted to say. Weird () are there because stack overflow automatically deletes anything in < ... > brackets, and I am too lazy to check why.